# Terraform : How to loop over aws_instance N times as defined within object

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**I have the following variable**

```
variable "instance_types" {

  default = {

    instances : [
      {
        count                  = 1
        name                   = "control-plane"
        ami                    = "ami-xxxxx"
        instance_type          = "t2.large"
        iam_instance_profile   = "xxx-user"
        subnet_id              = "subnet-xxxxx"
      },
      {
        count                  = 3
        name                   = "worker"
        ami                    = "ami-xxxxx"
        instance_type          = "t2.large"
        iam_instance_profile   = "xxx-user"
        subnet_id              = "subnet-xxxxx"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**With the following instance declaration (that I'm attempting to iterate)**

```
resource "aws_instance" "k8s-node" {

  # Problem here : How to turn an array of 2 objects into 4 (1 control_plane, 3 workers)
  for_each = {for x in var.instance_types.instances:  x.count => x}

  ami                    = lookup(each.value, "ami")
  instance_type          = lookup(each.value, "instance_type")
  iam_instance_profile   = lookup(each.value, "iam_instance_profile")
  subnet_id              = lookup(each.value, "subnet_id")

  tags = {
    Name      = lookup(each.value, "name")
    Type      = each.key
  }
}
```

**Goal:** Get the `aws_instance` to iterate 4 times (1 control_plane + 3 workers) and populate the values the index of `instance_types`.

**Problem :** Cannot iterate the over the object array correctly with desired result. In a typical programming language this would be achieved in a double for loop.

Comment: This would be significantly easier as a `map(object))` type with `count` as the keys instead of a `map(list(object))` with a `for` expression data transformation. Is there something impeding you from choosing that type?

Comment: No I'm free to change the object structure. Could you demonstrate how this would be achieved in your recommendation. Keep in mind that object is not an exhaustive list. there could be more with the same number of counts

Comment: Ok so I actually see better now what you are trying to achieve. You want to generalize the k8s worker and control plane nodes into a single TF AWS instance resource. My comment is now slightly less valid, but answering along the same lines regardless.

Comment: Again keying off of number of instances will not suffice since several different instance types outside of these two will be included in this map

Comment: Unsure how that is relevant to my comments explaining the path forward, but answer will be finished shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved easier with a data type of `map(object))` for your input variable. The transformed data structure appears like:

```
variable "instance_types" {
  ...
  default = {
    "control-plane" = {
      count                  = 1
      ami                    = "ami-xxxxx"
      instance_type          = "t2.large"
      iam_instance_profile   = "xxx-user"
      subnet_id              = "subnet-xxxxx"
    },
    "worker" = {
      count                  = 3
      ami                    = "ami-xxxxx"
      instance_type          = "t2.large"
      iam_instance_profile   = "xxx-user"
      subnet_id              = "subnet-xxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

Note the `name` key in the `object` is subsumed into the `map` key for efficiency and cleanliness.

If the resources are split between the control plane and worker nodes, then we are finished and can immediately leverage this variable's value in a `for_each` meta-argument. However, combining the resources now requires a data transformation:

```
locals {
  instance_types = flatten([ # need this for final structure type
    for instance_key, instance in var.instance_types : [ # iterate over variable input objects
      for type_count in range(1, instance.count + 1) : { # sub-iterate over objects by "count" value specified; use range function and begin at 1 for human readability
        new_key              = "${instance_key} ${type_count}" # for resource uniqueness
        type                 = instance_key # for easier tag value later
        ami                  = instance.ami # this and below retained from variable inputs
        instance_type        = instance.instance_type
        iam_instance_profile = instance.iam_instance_profile
        subnet_id            = instance.subnet_id
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

Now we can iterate within the resource with the `for_each` meta-argument, and utilize the `for` expression to reconstruct the input for suitable usage within the resource.

```
resource "aws_instance" "k8s-node" {
  # local.instance_types is a list of objects, and we need a map of objects with unique resource keys
  for_each = { for instance_type in local.instance_types : instance_type.new_key => instance_type }

  ami                  = each.value.ami
  instance_type        = each.value.instance_type
  iam_instance_profile = each.value.iam_instance_profile
  subnet_id            = each.value.subnet_id

  tags = {
    Name = each.key
    Type = each.value.type
  }
}
```

This will give you the behavior you desire, and you can modify it for style preferences or different uses as the need arises.

Note the `lookup` functions are removed since they are only useful when default values are specified as a third argument, and that is not possible in object types within variable declarations except as an experimental feature in 0.14.

The absolute namespace for these resources' exported resource attributes would be:

```
(module?.<declared_module_name>?.)<resource_type>.<resource_name>[<resource_key>].<attribute>
```

For example, given an intra-module resource, first worker node, and private ip address exported attribute:

```
aws_instance.k8s-node["worker 1"].private_ip
```

Note you can also access all resources' exported attributes by terminating the namespace at `<resource_name>` (retaining the map of all resources instead of accessing a singular resource value). Then you could also use a `for` expression in an `output` declaration to create a custom aggregate output for all of the similar resources and their identical exported attribute(s).

```
{ for node_key, node in aws_instance.k8s-node : node_key => node.private_ip }
```

Comment: Trying this out now - much appreciate the response

Comment: @stackoverflow I know how annoying it must seem that you have to do a data transformation to do nested iterators like this, but it actually is the documented algorithm until native functionality exists (hopefully soon): https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each

Comment: Using the above I get this : 'This object does not have an attribute named "key".
' which is refering to 'type = instance.key'

Comment: @stackoverflow Total brain fart on my part for the temporary lambda iterator scope variables in the for expression on the map variable. Answer fixed.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help! And one last questions, if I were to output the private_ips of the 'workers' of the 'k8_nodes" how would one handle that?

Comment: @stackoverflow Added to answer.

Comment: Very helpful. so why then doesn't this work?   data "template_file" "ansible_template" {

  vars = {

    worker_hosts = aws_instance.k8s-node.*.private_ip
  }
}

Comment: Can I not just use the asterisk to call for all of the private ips?

Comment: @stackoverflow No, the splat operator `*` is for transformations of lists in versions < 0.12.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229668/discussion-between-stackoverflow-and-matt-schuchard).